# 'Missing $ inserted' error after adding Slovak language

Tags: babel, classicthesis

I am creating derivative work of classic thesis template from Andre Miede (http://www.miede.de/index.php?page=classicthesis). What I have done was adding option for slovak language into the document class like this:

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,%1headlines,% letterpaper a4paper
        footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,abstractoff, % <--- obsolete, remove (todo)
        BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,%11pt,a4paper,%
        ngerman,american,slovak%
        ]{scrreprt}
```

This is excerpt of error message I get when trying to compile the source file:

```
Package natbib Warning: Citation `knuth:1974' on page xi undefined on input lin
e 11.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `knuth:1974' on page xi undefined on input lin
e 11.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\eulervm\uzeur.fd")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\microtype\mt-eur.cfg")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\eulervm\uzeus.fd")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\microtype\mt-eus.cfg")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\eulervm\uzeuex.fd")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\psnfss\ot1zplm.fd")
Overfull \hbox (2.84056pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 27--36
[]\T1/pplj/m/n/10.95 Regarding the ty-pog-raphy and ot-her help, many thanks go
 to Marco
) [11] [12] (FrontBackmatter/Contents.tex (ChinesePoets.toc) [13]
(ChinesePoets.lof) (ChinesePoets.lot) (ChinesePoets.lol) [14]) [1] [2]
(Chapters/Chapter01.tex
Kapitola 1.
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.7     Master'
               s
?
```

This is relevant part of source file Chapter01.tex:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Provide students with an easy-to-use template for their
    Master's
    or PhD thesis. (Though it might also be used by other types of
    authors
    for reports, books, etc.)
    \item Provide a classic, high-quality typographic style that is
    inspired by \citeauthor{bringhurst:2002}'s ``\emph{The Elements of
    Typographic Style}'' \citep{bringhurst:2002}.
    \marginpar{\myTitle \myVersion}
\end{enumerate}
```

It seems like the LaTex compiler has problem with apostrophe character '. Why is this happening ? Please explain it in simple way because most of my life I have used tools like Word and OpenOffice Writer. I have minimal experiences with TeX systems. Just recently finished reading introductory book into LaTeX system.

P.S. The problem can be reproduced on this simple document:

```
\documentclass[ twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,%1headlines,% letterpaper a4paper
                footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,abstractoff, % <--- obsolete, remove (todo)
                BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,%11pt,a4paper,%
                ngerman,american,slovak%
                ]{scrreprt}

%********************************************************************
% Note: Make all your adjustments in here
%*******************************************************
\input{classicthesis-config}

%********************************************************************
% Hyphenation
%*******************************************************
%\hyphenation{put special hyphenation here}

% ********************************************************************
% GO!GO!GO! MOVE IT!
%*******************************************************
\begin{document}
\frenchspacing
\raggedbottom
%\renewcommand*{\bibname}{new name}
%\setbibpreamble{}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}
%********************************************************************
% Frontmatter
%*******************************************************

%************************************************
\chapter{Introduction}\label{ch:introduction}
%************************************************
This bundle for \LaTeX\ has two goals:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Provide students with an easy-to-use template for their
    Master's
    or PhD thesis. (Though it might also be used by other types of
    authors
    for reports, books, etc.)
    \item Provide a classic, high-quality typographic style that is
    inspired by \citeauthor{bringhurst:2002}'s ``\emph{The Elements of
    Typographic Style}'' \citep{bringhurst:2002}.
    \marginpar{\myTitle \myVersion}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please always post a document that reproduces the error, I tried to construct a document from the preamble and `enumerate` that you posted but just get `LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [ngerman,american,slovak].

No file ff500.aux.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.15     inspired by \citeauthor`

Comment: You do know that *this simple document* is a lump of mostly unneded code, right?

Comment: Sorry but I didnt know on beginning where is the source of problem. The ClassicThesis template consists of 17 different files and I am not accustomed to error messages of TexWorks.

Comment: Your example is now 500!!! lines long and still doesn't reproduce the error in the question `! LaTeX Error: File \`classicthesis-config.tex' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: tex)

Enter file name: 

LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [ngerman,american,slovak].

(./ff500.aux)
Chapter 1.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.82     inspired by \citeauthor`

Comment: classicthesis is part of MikTex installation which is mainstream TeX software.

Comment: That is not the point, the point os providing an example that lets us (anybody reading the question) reproduce the cause of error, *without* searching for extra files.

Comment: Load `classicthesis` first. Hell, that is a mess.

Comment: `\documentclass[slovak]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\begin{document}
Master's
\end{document}
`

Comment: @Johannes_B - Even with the `classicthesis` package loaded, I still can't compile the file since my system is lacking the file `classicthesis_config.tex`.

Comment: @Mico As the hunter and destroyer of templates, i got it ;-)

Comment: What are extra files and what are not ? How should I distinguish it ? I downloaded and installed big software package MikTeX which is one of two currently being used by most of users (the other being TeX Live). Isn't the MikTeX standard ? Then what is the standard in the TeX world ? Its really not possible to simplify the example even further with my knowledge. If I knew this than I would also know answer to my question.

Comment: @Johannes_B - Is that your new title -- "Hunter and destroyer of templates"? You may want to adopt a hunter avatar, say, an image of a wolf or a grizzly bear. :-) Purple squares and triangles aren't nearly fearsome enough...

Comment: @Mico http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=20128256#20128256

Comment: @Johannes_B -- Gundar demands something more awe-inspiring than purple squares and triangles. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classicthesis does a mess, so does the config-file that is provided with the template bundlle. Simple advice, don't use it.

Simple solution to the stated problem is to load package `classicthesis` before loading the config file.

After reducing everything that is irrelevant for the stated problem, we come to the following.

```
\documentclass[slovak]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\begin{document}
Master's
\end{document}
```

The slovak-option of `babel` seems to do strange stuff.
Load babel after setting the font, and everything is fine.

Comment: Unfortunetaly this solves only partially problem. The simplified example compiles correctly, but the real document not. I can't exclude possibility that its because of your workaround. Now I receive error "Undefined control sequence \ctparttext". Its really not that simple to simplify real complex example. There are too many variables included.

Comment: It has to do with babel shorthands. If I disable them be defining command \usepackage[shorthands=off]{babel} problem disappears. It doesnt help to switch to english language before chapters written in english with command \selectlanguage{american}. The latex persists on using shorthands defined for slovak language. The solution would be to use english shorthands for english texts and slovak shorthands for slovak texts. Unfortunately I cannot find documentation with all the shorthands supported for particular language.

Comment: If i take your example, load `classicthesis` *before* the config-file that comes with the template bundle, the error disappears. Please provide a minimal working example that reproduces the error for us. Everybody is encouraged to change the config file (which is quite useless to tell the truth). I cannot know what has been changed in yours.

Comment: After `documentclass`, do `\usepackage{eulervm}`.

Comment: After loading classicthesis on beginning of config-file as you suggested and with all the original options i.e.
\PassOptionsToPackage{eulerchapternumbers,listings,drafting,    pdfspacing,subfig,beramono,eulermath,parts}{classicthesis}          
\usepackage{classicthesis} 

all problems disappeared. I was not successfull at first try because I have not specified any of optional parameters to classicthesis package.

Comment: @truthseeker I am glad the issue could be resolved.